# I can't change telegram token in Integration section of Dialogflow. "Bot was not stopped"

Tags: dialogflow-es, telegram

I have Dialogflow support bot integrated with telegram bot for our customer support.
All worked fine.
Recently token of telegram bot was changed. 
Of course, telegram bot now doesn't answer because token was changed and now it is not linked with Dialogflow.
And I can't modify token in Dialogflow - field with token is grey-colored and cannot be edited.

I can only click STOP in Telegram integration window where I can see "Bot was not stopped".

Any suggestions?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Until this publication did not resolve, it is a mistake of Dialogflow. According to this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145900985#comment4), you have to create a new agent and link a new token to a new Telegram bot to work ... that is, redo everything again.

Answer (score 0):

To update the token you can follow these instructions:

- Go to the "Integrations" UI, and select "Telegram"
- Use the blue toggle in the right corner to deactivate the integration with telegram (See the blue toggle in [the image](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/integrations/telegram#setting_up_dialogflow) for reference)
- Click on the toggle again (it is now grey) to activate the integration
- You can now update the token
- After making the changes in the token, select "START"

Taken from [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145900985#comment4)